# JSON Object property into JSON Object name

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, notation

I have a JSON file with a lot of objects like this (e.g. properties of Pikemen unit >Heroes 3 btw<):

```
[ {
        "ID": 0,
        "AI": 80,
        "": null,
        "Level": 0,
        "Growth": 14,
        "Low": 20,
        "High": 50,
        "Town": 0,
        "Name": "Pikeman",
    }, etc.. ]
```

How could I make `"Name"` property the name of every object in my JSON file? Either in JS code or through formatting file. What I mean is:

```
[ "Pikeman": {
       "ID": 0,
       "AI": 80,
       etc..
} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
let obj = [{
        "ID": 0,
        "AI": 80,
        "": null,
        "Level": 0,
        "Growth": 14,
        "Low": 20,
        "High": 50,
        "Town": 0,
        "Name": "Pikeman",
    },{
        "ID": 0,
        "AI": 82220,
        "": null,
        "Level": 230,
        "Growth": 14,
        "Low": 20213,
        "High": 12312050,
        "Town": 10,
        "Name": "Pikeman2",
    }]

obj.forEach((item, index) => {
  obj[item.Name] = item;
  delete obj[index];
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I have a lot of objects like this. I need some kind of loop to do this, because file is too long

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Adrian You can iterate through your array and obtain the name and assign int as a key check this:

```
let obj = [ {
        "ID": 0,
        "AI": 80,
        "": null,
        "Level": 0,
        "Growth": 14,
        "Low": 20,
        "High": 50,
        "Town": 0,
        "Name": "Pikeman",
    }, 
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "AI": 80,
        "": null,
        "Level": 0,
        "Growth": 14,
        "Low": 20,
        "High": 50,
        "Town": 0,
        "Name": "Pikeman1",
    }, 
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "AI": 80,
        "": null,
        "Level": 0,
        "Growth": 14,
        "Low": 20,
        "High": 50,
        "Town": 0,
        "Name": "Pikema2",
    }]

    let objConverted = {};

    obj.forEach( o => {
      objConverted[o.Name] = o; 
    } ) 

    console.log(objConverted);
```

Check this if you wanna play with the code : https://repl.it/repls/HalfSatisfiedMainframe

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot for useful tool